# GC_CONCURRENT freed 1841K and KILLED my MediaPlayer

Tags: android

**SOLVED: needed to declare MP globally.**

I have a MediaPlayer playing/looping a sound.

```
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
```

and it works fine until I suddenly get

```
D/dalvikvm(14090): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1841K, 51% free 4335K/8839K, external 10702K/12379K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

in logcat and MP dies. Any ideas what might have happened and how do I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before `mp.start()`

`mp.setLooping(True)`

Then set false when you want to stop it looping.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it. same result, dies with "GC_CONCURRENT freed..."

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Just needed to declare MP globally and it works!

Comment: You mean you've added it to a member variable or static variable. The reason it was released is because as a local variable, it came out of scope when your method has returned, i.e. you had no reference to it (no directed path existed to it from none of the GC roots, to be precise). Therefore, it was eligible for garbage collection, and its finalizer was run. The managed finalizer of MediaPlayer calls it native finalizer, which in turns releases the underlying native MediaPlayer/AudioTrack. This is why your sound playback died.